# download remote gz files that reside in a tree like directories does snot work

Tags: python, ftp

I have been scratching my head for more than 2 days, but still cannot figure out how to do the following!
I want to download all Geo data sets that are in ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov and then in each data set, I need to see if they contain the keywords that I am interested in.  I was able to manually download one of the data sets and checked the file for the desired keywords. However, since the number of data sets are huge, I cannot do it manually. I want to write a program to do it for me. For the first step, I just tried to see if I can download them.
The structure is as follows:

```
 hots-> 
  /geo/ 
     -> datasets/ 
       ->  GDS1nnn/ .... all the way through GDS6nnn and each of them 
           contain more than 600 directories; ordered by number i.e. 
            GDS1001. Now, in each of these directories:
           --->  soft  inside this folder there are 2 files that are named 
            like this: folder name (GDS1001)+_full.soft.gz
```

this is the file that I think I need to download and then see if the keywords that I am looking for are inside that file.

Here is my code:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov') # remember that you ONLY need to provide the host name not the complete address!
ftp.login()
#ftp.retrlines('LIST')
ftp.cwd("/geo/datasets/GDS1nnn/")
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
filenames = ftp.nlst() 
count = len(filenames)
curr = 0
print ("found {} files".format(count))
for filename in filenames:
    first_path=filename+"/soft/"
    second_path=first_path+filename+"_full.soft.gz"
    #print(second_path)  
    local_filename = os.path.join(r'full path to a folder that I 
         created')
    file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + second_path, file.write)
    file.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Output:

```
file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: full path to a folder that I created'
```

However, I have both read and write permission on this folder.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you have two `for filename in filenames:` loops? All the first one does is assign values to `first_path` and `second_path` over-and-over again. Note also that the second `for` loop will use the **last** value that was assigned to `second_path` in the first loop. Not sure if this has anything to do with the permissions issue, but it's clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how you can create a folder for each dataset and save their content into that folder.

```
 import sys, ftplib, os, itertools
    from ftplib import FTP
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    ftp = FTP('ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov')
    ftp.login()
    #ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    ftp.cwd("/geo/datasets/GDS1nnn/")
    ftp.retrlines('LIST') 
    filenames = ftp.nlst()
    curr = 0
    #print ("found {} files".format(count))
    count = 0
    for filename in filenames:
        array_db=[]   
        os.mkdir( os.path.join('folder called "output' + filename ) )
        first_path=filename+"/soft/"
        os.mkdir( os.path.join('folder called "output' + first_path ) )
        second_path=first_path+filename+"_full.soft.gz"
        array_db.append(second_path)    
        for array in array_db:
            print(array)
            local_filename = os.path.join('folder called "output' + array )
            file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + array, file.write)
            file.flush()
            file.close()    
    ftp.quit()
```